# Phpmyadmin "Error in processing request" when export table - Error code 500

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to use PhpMyAdmin v. 4.5.3.1 to access a DB on a localhost and export a table but it is not working.
I can access the DB, insert, search, etc. but when I click on "Export" tab it gives me this message:

[image]

I don't have this issue with PhpMyAdmin 4.2.6 using the same WAMP....

Does anyone knows how to fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: As @clean_coding mentioned, the webserver error log should contain more information about what went wrong here. Without information from the error logs, we're just kind of guessing about what might be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use mysqldump instead, when exporting data. From the command line:

```
mysqldump -uMYSQL-USER -h server -pMYSQL-USER database_name > /path-to-export
```

Or from a script:

```
$command = "mysqldump -uMYSQL-USER -h server -pMYSQL-USER database_name > /path-to-export/file.sql";
exec($command, $output, $return_var);
```

This can easily be automated.

Comment: Thank you! But do you know why it works for PhpMyAdmin v. 4.2.6?

Comment: You will have to check the error log, but there is many possibilities. I experienced it because the dataset was too large to export from PhpMyAdmin. Is it the same table and data you try to export in the different versions?

Comment: Yes. Same table on both versions. It gives me same error with phpMyAdmin-4.4.15.2 too.

Comment: Sounds strange, but did you try checking the logs? The error message is not much to go on.

Answer (score 0):

You could fix this error by increasing memory limit to your requirement and restart httpd/apache service. I fixed it sometimes by increasing memory_limit. But now i prefer to use terminal commands only to handle it. Its better to always get habitual using terminal commands for doing such big operations in mysql. You get speed and more control over it as you are not dependent upon GUI based systems.

1. Use mysqldump in terminal to export data:
   mysqldump -u root -p db_name > /home/dump.sql
2. Use mysqldump in terminal to export only schema without data:
   mysqldump -u root -p db_name --no-data > /home/dump.sql